# How to Mint NFT to Exist Collenction with Smart Contract?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

i want to mint Collection NFT. but each time mint nft with hardhat, in OpenSea Create New Collection.

I Inheritance in my contract from "@OpenZeppelin/ERC721URIStorage"
and mint contract to poligon polygon mumbai blockchain.

```
contract MoriNFT is ERC721URIStorage {
...
}
```

Comment: Please state your question more precisely and add additional information, for being able to provide specific help.

Answer (score 0):

for create nft collection need to inheritance form "ERC721Enumerable" contract and mint collection to blockchain

for check this contract use [ERC721Enumerable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol) link